# Using log4cxx as input counter

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I want to add a counter that record how many data input per hour or per day.

Since there is no timer in my code, I hope that log4cxx, which can handle daily log rotation, could help me. Like, every midnight, print a log showing how many data got in yesterday.

Do anyone know the trick or any reference?

THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer, but maybe it's going to be useful to other people.

Nope, log4cxx cannot do it — print a log at a given time, out of itself. Log4cxx is not about timers, roll-over detection routine is checked with every log statement processed by the library, more specific, by the appender. There are no watchdog threads to trigger any behaviour.

Comment: It's never too late to answer a question.